# undefined is not an object evaluating _this.props.navigation

Tags: react-native

```
class Login extends Component {
render() {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <Card>
        <CardSection>
          <Button onPress={() => navigate('SignUp')}>
             ForgotPass?
         </Button>

        </CardSection>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my code, I tried to go to the "SignUp" page without success. someone?
why its not work?
I know this is a simple problem but I have tried many times without success

```
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import FirstScreen from './src/HomePage/FirstScreen';
import Login from './src/Login/Login';
import LogOut from './src/LogOut/LogOut';
import SignUp from './src/SignUp/SignUp';
import HomeScreen from './src/HomeScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './src/ProfileScreen';


const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {

  First: FirstScreen,
  LogOut : LogOut,
  Login: Login,
  SignUp: SignUp,
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Profile: ProfileScreen,
  },
  {
  initialRouteName : 'First',
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    title: "FrienDog"
  }
}
);

const App = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);


export default App;
```

This is my app.js file, i cant move to signup page.
please help me.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Login extends Component {
render() {
    return (
     <Container>
       <Card>
         <CardSection>
           <Button onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUp')}
             title='ForgotPass?'>
         </Button>
        </CardSection>
      </Card>
    </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, now that I click the button I get the following error:  "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this3.props.navigation.navigate')"